# Removing anonymous event handlers

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C#: How to remove a lambda event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362204/c-how-to-remove-a-lambda-event-handler)

Is it possible to remove an event handler which was attached as anonymous function?  Let's say I have an event, and I subscribe to it in this way:

```
TestClass classs = new TestClass ();
classs.myCustomEvent +=  (a,b) => { Console.Write(""); };
```

Is it possible somehow to remove this eventHandler using -= ??

Answer (score 24):

It is possible, but you need to store it in a local variable first:

```
MyDelegate handler = (a, b) => { Console.Write(""); };
class.myCustomEvent += handler;
class.myCustomEvent -= handler;
```

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted... +1, this is a correct answer. Except the part about the "local" variable: in most scenarios you will need to store it in a more long lived location...