# Events with lambda expression

Tags: c#, winforms, lambda

I need someone to help me with this little problem I have. Here's a code fragment:

```
void shuffle() 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

        // here should be the computations of x and y

        buttons[i].Click += (s, e) => { show_coordinates(x, y); };

        // shuffling going on
    }
}

void show_coordinates(int x, int y)
{
    MessageBox.Show(x + " " + y);
}
```

as you can see I create a new event handler with different x and y for each button every time I run the loop. There's another button in my form which shuffles the buttons randomly.

So here's the problem: If I press the shuffle button say 10 times and then press any of the shuffled buttons, event handlers stack up and I get 10 message boxes displaying x and y values.

So how can I overwrite the previous event handler with a new one each time I press shuffle.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like this would not compile as `x` and `y` do not exist at the point the lambda is constructed.

Comment: True indeed, however the compiler would probably tell him that to :)
And as he wrote he already managed to get the result 10 times when he clicks on it. We can expect that he just omitted that particular code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would redesign the code instead to do something like this:

```
private PointF[] points = new PointF[4];

//Run once
public void Initialize()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        buttons[i].Click += (s, e) => { show_coordinates(i); };
}

public void Shuffle()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
    {
        // here should be the computations of x and y
        points[i] = new PointF(x,y);
        // shuffling going on
    }
}

public void show_coordinates(int index)
{
    var point = points[index];
    MessageBox.Show(point.X + " " + point.Y);
}
```

Comment: Using class indepently works nice. Be aware that leaving event handlers uncleared will result memoryleaks (atleast in winforms I have encountered this in a form of object handles)

Answer (score 0):

Reflection is a one way to do it, but i would prefer a delegate and adding/removing that delegate. This leads to easier maintainable code than using a reflection:

[How to remove a lambda event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362204/c-how-to-remove-a-lambda-event-handler)

Comment: You mentioned removal of delegates. But will it work in this particular situation. Do I have to create an array to hold a delegate for each button?

Comment: Heres an good example of using delegates http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173172.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop first remove the event handlers then re-add them.
However take into account that this is bad practice. You should use the button's datacontext and bind an object to it containing your x and y values.
This way you only have to attach your event handler once. Instead of every time shuffle get's called. Then updating your buttons datacontext is way more convenient.

```
Example PseudoCode:
public MainWindow() {
ForEach Button addEvent(DoSomething);
ForEach Button Button.Datacontext = new Data();
}

public class Data {
prop X;
prop Y;
ctor(x,y)
ctor()
}

public void DoSomething()
{
var data = Button.datacontext as data
MessageBox(data.x, data.y)
}

public void Shuffle()
{
calc x, y
foreach Button (Button.datacontext as data).x = x, ...
}
```

Comment: DataContext is a WPF thingy, the question is tagged WinForms.

Comment: Completely looked over that, In winforms instead of datacontext one could use the Tag (if that is a string then the tag in combination with a dictionary)

Comment: Tag can be anything, the Tag property is of type Object.

Comment: In that case you can just set the tag as the data object and then instead of getting the datacontext, you can get the Data object, the same way I showed in my pseudo code example.