# How can I remove a Loaded event handler in DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm trying to dynamically load columns when `DataGrid` is loaded, and add the event handler with some parameters in initialization.

```
dataGrid.Loaded += (sender, args) => AddColumns(dataGrid, GetAttachedColumns(dataGrid));
```

But have no idea to how to remove this handler after DataGrid is loaded. The following code doesn't work.

```
dataGrid.Loaded -= (sender, args) => AddColumns(dataGrid, GetAttachedColumns(dataGrid));
```

Please help out. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In cases when you need to explicitly remove the event listener, you can't really use an anonymous handler.  Try a plain old method:

```
private void DataGridLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
{
    AddColumns(dataGrid, GetAttachedColumns(dataGrid));
}
```

Which you can then simply add/remove:

```
dataGrid.Loaded += DataGridLoaded;
dataGrid.Loaded -= DataGridLoaded;
```

---

Alternatively, if you really wanted to use the lambda form, you could hold onto a reference in a member variable.  Eg:

```
public class MyControl
{
    private RoutedEventHandler _handler;

    public void Subscribe()
    {
        _handler = (sender, args) => AddColumns(dataGrid, GetAttachedColumns(dataGrid));
        dataGrid.Loaded -= _handler;
    }

    public void Unsubscribe()
    {
        dataGrid.Loaded -= _handler;
    }
}
```

See also other questions:

- [How to remove a lambda event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1362244/1001985)

Comment: Thanks a lot. The second solution is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: How to check if there are event listeners on the datagridview? if there are non, whould that `dataGrid.Loaded -= DataGridLoaded;` give an error?