# Event Driven Programming

Tags: c#

I've been reading [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edzehd2t(v=vs.110).aspx) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803242/understanding-events-and-event-handlers-in-c-sharp) to try to understand events in .NET. Unfortunately, its not clicking for me and I'm having a lot of trouble. I'm trying to integrate this technique into my project, with little success.

Basically, I've got this class that will read numbers. Whenever it encounters a new number, I want it to fire an event called numberChanged.

So, I set up my event `public event EventHandler numberChanged;`. Later on, I fire my event when it encounters a number than isn't the same as the previous one.

```
if(currentNumber != previousNumber){
     if(numberChanged != null){
          numberChanged(this, new EventArgs());
     }
}
```

But then I'm having trouble 'subscibing' to this event. If I do `numberChanged += [something to do here]` it errors saying that numberChanged is an event and not a type.

Is my explanation clear enough for some advice to be offered? Many thanks.

Comment: you should subscribe the event like this : yourclassInstance.numberChanged+=()=>{}; or numberChanged+=functionSignature;

Comment: @HadiHassan Can you clarify on what comes after the +=?

Comment: The expression after the "+=" needs to be a delegate of the same type as the event declaration.  This could be the name of a declared method, or an anonymous method (which uses the `()=>{}` syntax).

Comment: it should be like this: yourClass.EventName += FunctionThatHandlesTheEvent(int example, string example2)

Comment: Can you post the exact code that is causing the error?  Your [something to do here] code is likely causing the issue.

Comment: @BJMyers Its just a method name that I'd rather not show

Comment: Creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would make it easier for others to help you debug.

Comment: @JesseShellabarger check my answer, if you need more help go ahead, better in my opinion to define your own delegate to fire the numberchanged with 2 params ( old value and new value) by this it will be more resuable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a number of ways to handle it, the most basic is to create a function:

```
public void MyNumberChangedHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Your code goes here that gets called when the number changes
}
```

You then subscribe (one time only, usually in the constructor) by going:

```
numberChanged += MyNumberChangedHandler;
```

Or, you can use something called an anonymous (lambda) method, which is also assigned in your constructor (typically):

```
numberChanged += (sender, e) => {
    //Your code here to handle the number changed event
};
```

To expand a little bit, care must be taken when using the lambda approach since you can create memory leaks and zombie objects. The .NET memory garbage collector is a mark-and-sweep system that removes objects when they are no longer in use. This post shows how hard it is to remove lambda event handlers: [How to remove a lambda event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362204/how-to-remove-a-lambda-event-handler) .

Having an active event handler can keep your object alive **even if it has been disposed!** Here is an example of creating a zombie object (doesn't run in Fiddle but you can copy to your own console app) https://dotnetfiddle.net/EfNpZ5

Prints out:

```
I'm still alive
I'm still alive
I was disposed!
Press any key to quit
I'm still alive
I'm still alive
I'm still alive.
```

Comment: While on the topic of programatically adding event handlers, what's the difference from something like this: `myButton.Click += new EventHandler(myButton_Click);` versus `myButton.Click += myButton_Click` ?

Comment: @sab669 Nothing technically.

Comment: @sab669 It's just a syntactic sugar introduced in C# 2.0

Comment: The `IDisposable.Dispose` method is used to release unmanaged resources and is not related to freeing managed memory. The relation between `IDisposable.Dispose` and the garbage collector is that if you have a `Dispose` method that releases unmanaged resources you need to create a finalizer to ensure that the unmanaged resources are released even if `Dispose` is never called. This has nothing to do with leaking event handlers.

Comment: @MartinLiversage Sorry, not sure I 100% understood that. At my previous job I got in the habbit of having an `AttachEvents()` method which would attach events with the `new EventHandler()` syntax, then we'd have a `DettachEvents()` method which we'd call from the form designer's `Dispose()` method. Never did learn *why* we did that. I was under the impression that was the GC's job basically. Is that, more or less, what you're referring to?

Comment: @MartinLiversage I understand that, however you can use the `Dispose` method to do other things on deconstruction aside from releasing unmanaged resources. For example, placing the object in a `using` block causes the `Dispose` method to be called, where you can perform clean up of the object. The point I was trying to make is that the GC can keep an object alive if you don't get rid of event handlers.

Answer (score 4):

As everything else in the C# programming world, the events concept also follows specific rules and has it's own syntax. The wording is as follows:

- an event defined as [EventHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is actually just a shortcut for a special method (delegate) **signature** - `public delegate void EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)`[1]. Whenever you have a signature in C# you always know what you need to write on the right sight or as a parameter, in order to connect/call some objects/methods/and so on.
- after the event is defined, you need to subscribe in order to be informed whenever something happens. The syntax for subscribing an event is **+=**. Naturally for unsubscribing is **-=**. MSDN says that the syntax should be `object.event += eventHandler` (or `object.event += new EventHandler(eventHandler);`)
- so after an event is defined (`event Event SomeEvent;`) all that left is to create a method that can be bound to this event. This method **has to have** the same signature as the EventHandler, so it should match the signature of [1] and can be something like `private void numberChangedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs eventArguments)`

Now you know what you need to write on the right side of **+=**.

An example:

```
public class NumberSequence
{
    // numbers to be compared
    private readonly List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
    // used to generate a random collection
    private readonly Random random = new Random();
    // tell me if the previous and next number are different
    public event EventHandler DifferentNumbersEvent;

    public NumberSequence()
    {
        // fill the list with random numbers
        Enumerable.Range(1, 100).ToList().ForEach(number =>
        {
            numbers.Add(random.Next(1, 100));
        });
    }

    public List<int> Numbers { get { return numbers; } }

    public void TraverseList()
    {
        for (var i = 1; i < this.numbers.Count; i++)
        {
            if (this.numbers[i - 1] != this.numbers[i])
            {
                if (this.DifferentNumbersEvent != null)
                {
                    // whoever listens - inform him
                    this.DifferentNumbersEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now before the class is used, define the event handler, that will *listen* and will be called, when the event is *fired* (wording again):

```
private void differentNumberEventHandler(Object sender, EventArgs eventArguments)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Different numbers...");
}
```

And the usage:

```
var ns = new NumberSequence();
ns.DifferentNumbersEvent += differentNumberEventHandler;
ns.TraverseList();
```

Everything else is just [*syntactic sugar*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) for this notation (lambda / anonymous methods / ...), for example:

`object.Event += (s, e) => { // code ... };` is the same as `object.Event += (Object sender, EventArgs eventArguments) => { // code ... };`. Do you recognise the signature? - it is the same as the `private void differentNumberEventHandler...`.

Often we need to pass information through the event, in this case maybe we want to see the two numbers. C# allows you to do this easily using custom event arguments. Just create a class that inherits the `EventArgs` class and add properties for the data that should be passed, in this case the numbers:

```
public class NumbersInfoEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public int Number1 { get; set; }
    public int Number2 { get; set; }
}
```

And then specify, when declaring the event, that it will pass data of type `NumbersInfoEventArgs` (signatures again):

```
public event EventHandler<NumbersInfoEventArgs> DifferentNumbersEvent;
...
this.DifferentNumbersEvent(this, new NumbersInfoEventArgs
{
    Number1 = this.numbers[i - 1],
    Number2 = this.numbers[i]
});
```

And last but now least, the signature of the event handler *should* match the signature of the event:

```
private void differentNumberEventHandler(Object sender, NumbersInfoEventArgs eventArguments)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Different numbers {0} - {1}", eventArguments.Number1, eventArguments.Number2);
}
```

And voila, the output is:

```
Different numbers 89 - 86
Different numbers 86 - 53
Different numbers 53 - 12
Different numbers 12 - 69
```

Comment: As far as best-practices go, any class that extends the `EventArgs` class should include the words "EventArgs", for example, `NumbersInfo` should be called `NumbersInfoEventArgs`. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edzehd2t(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: thank you for the hint (sometimes in my SO euphoria I tend to forget about the guidelines), I've updated my code.

Answer (score 1):

you can subscribe the event in this way:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        var num = new Number();
        num.numberChanged +=(s,e) =>{
            Console.WriteLine("Value was changed to {0}",num.Value); // in the demo below you can find another implementation for this sample using custom events
        };
        num.Value=10;
        num.Value=100;
    }
}

public class Number{
    public event EventHandler numberChanged;
    private int _value=0;
    public int Value
    {
        get{
            return _value;
        }
        set{
            if(value!=_value){
                _value=value;
                if(numberChanged!=null)
                    numberChanged(this,null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

explanation:

since the EventHandler delegate has 2 parameters (sender, eventArgs) as mentioned [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler(v=vs.110).aspx), you need to pass these params and I passed them as **s** and **e**

another way to subscribe this event like this:

```
var num = new Number();
num.numberChanged += NumberChanged_Event; // below is the delegate method

public void NumberChanged_Event(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
   // your code goes here
}
```

I updated the demo to work with you own delegate to pass the old value and new value which can help in many cases.

here a working [demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6UL8TY)