# How to destroy class object with timer property on null or new instance assignment to class instance variable in c#?

Tags: c#, timer

I have a class which has a **System.Timers.Timer** property. The timer will start on object creation using a constructor.

**Class definition:**

```
public class Temp
{
    public int ID { get; set; } = 0;
    public System.Timers.Timer Timer { get; set; } = null;

    public Temp(int id)
    {
        ID = id;
        Timer = new System.Timers.Timer(5000);
        Timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
        Timer.Enabled = true;
        Timer.Start();
        Console.Write(this.ID + "Class Constructor");
    }

    private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.Write(this.ID + "Timer_Elapsed");
    }

    ~Temp()
    {
        Console.Write(this.ID + "Class Distructor");
    }
}
```

**Note:**

*I am not calling **Timer.Stop()** method or setting **Timer.Enable = false** anywhere in the class. It means that the timer will be destroyed only when the **destructor is called**. I wrote a destructor to know when the class is being destroyed.*

**Requirement:**

*I need to stop or destroy the timer when I assign a null value or new instance to the class instance variable. I don't want to handle timer from outside of the class by making it public and implement methods like **temp.Dispose()** or **temp.StopTimer()** etc where the timer will be stopped and then assign a new Temp class instance to temp variable.*

**Code sample for the usage of class:**

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Temp temp = new Temp(1);
        temp = null; // Or line not nacessary.
        temp = new Temp(2);
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForFullGCComplete();
        Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
    }
}
```

**My current understanding or assumptions when the timer will be destroyed:**

**1. On exit of the program:**

Works perfectly.
   *Destructor is called twice instead of once.* **Not sure if this is normal?**

**2. On assignment of null to the variable:**

I am assuming that when a null value is assigned or new instance is assigned old instance is *eligible for garbage collection*. So I am expecting a *call to the destructor*. But it is *not getting called*. **Is there any time or memory limit when the destructor is called or null assignment will not call garbage collector?**

**3.** In c# we can't call the destructor explicitly.

**4.** Explicitly call garbage collection is not working.

**Is there any other way of doing this?**

Comment: You should be implementing IDisposable, not using that destructor. Then make sure to call it when you are done with the object.

Comment: This read may help you: Deterministic finalization 
 by Juval Lowy https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/programming-net-components/0596102070/ch04s05.html

Comment: Implemented IDisposable from this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose So, because Timer is an unmanaged type we need to implement IDIsposable and call Dispose method like **temp.Dispose()** and dispose of Timer in Dispose method by calling **Timer.Dispose()** and **!! I have to destroy Timer manually !!**. And also **still destructor is not called any explanation for this will be helpful**

Comment: .Net doesn't work how your requirements are written. You can't implicitly call the destructor when you assign a new value. What you are creating is a memory leak and wanting the framework to deal with it on your behalf. Destructors (it's actually a finalizer) don't behave that way. This can't be done. You need to use and call dispose.

Comment: The finalizer isn't called because you have a circular reference inside the object. Assigning it a new value orphans the old value but the framework doesn't call the finalizer because there is still an active reference. It only calls it when the program exits (and yes, it may call it multiple times which is why you have a disposed flag) because it's cleaning up all references when the process shuts down. This is a memory leak.

Comment: @RonBeyer - Are you sure about the circular reference? I don't think that stops the GC from cleaning it up. It's only when it has a reference to pinned reference and neither of those references would be pinned.

Comment: @Enigmativity I'm fairly certain, I [demonstrated it about 4 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31462316/event-driven-programming/31462446#31462446) on a slightly different topic but the principle is the same.

Comment: @RonBeyer - The demonstration is correct, but it is a different situation here. In your demo your event handler is external to the object. In this case the handler is internal and that allows the proper clean up.

Answer (score 1):

> 2. On assignment of null to the variable:
>
> I am assuming that when a null value is assigned or new instance is
>   assigned old instance is eligible for garbage collection. So I am
>   expecting a call to the destructor. But it is not getting called. Is
>   there any time or memory limit when the destructor is called or null
>   assignment will not call garbage collector?

**Close, but incorrect.** 
When there are no remaining references to the object, which *may* coincide to when you set your reference to null (if there are no other references, even non-obvious references like something subscribed to one of your object's events), then it becomes eligible to be garbage collected.  The finalizer won't be called until it actually *is* garbage collected, however; not when it becomes eligible.  The GC may choose not to collect your object, even if it can.  If an object wasn't eligible last time the GC ran, the GC guesses that it won't be eligible the next time, and pushes it to a higher tier.  Long-lifetime objects often get pinned until full tier 2 GC runs (which may be never, if memory pressure isn't high enough).  As a general rule, if you are relying on the GC to finalize your object at some deterministic time, you are doing something wrong.

> I need to stop or destroy the timer when I assign a null value or new
>   instance to the class instance variable

You need to use reference counting, not automatic garbage collection, to meet this requirement.  To do this, place your reference in a property of something else, and use that to implicitly track references:

```
public class MyTimerReference {
   private Temp temp = null;
   public Temp Value { 
      get {
          return temp;
      } 
      set {
          var oldRef = temp;
          if (value != null)
              value.AddRef();
          temp = value;
          if (oldRef != null)
              oldRef.ReleaseRef();   
      }
   }
}

public class Temp
{
    public int ID { get; set; } = 0;
    public System.Timers.Timer Timer { get; set; } = null;

    public Temp(int id)
    {
        ID = id;
        Timer = new System.Timers.Timer(5000);
        Timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
        Timer.Enabled = true;
        Timer.Start();
        Console.Write(this.ID + "Class Constructor");
    }

    private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.Write(this.ID + "Timer_Elapsed");
    }

    private int refCount = 0;
    void AddRef() {
       refCount++;
    }

    void ReleaseRef() {
       refCount--;
       if (refCount == 0) {
          Timer.Stop();
          Console.Write(this.ID + "stopped");
       }
    }
}
```

Now you can, with an instance of `MyTimerReference` do something like this:

```
myTimerReference.Value = new Temp();  
myTimerReference.Value = null;  //this will cause the old `Temp` instance to cleanup
```

Or

```
var ref1 = new MyTimerReference();
var ref2 = new MyTimerReference();

ref1.Value = new Temp(); //timer gets started
ref2.Value = ref1.Value; //nothing happens
ref1.Value = null; //nothing happens
ref2.Value = new Temp(); //first timer stops, second timer starts
ref2.Value = null; //second timer stops
```