# Use of unassigned local variable when creating an anonymous function closing on itself

Tags: c#, .net, variables, delegates, unassigned-variable

Why does this declaration+assignment cause an error:

```
// Use of unassigned local variable 'handler'.
SessionEndingEventHandler handler = (sender, e) => { isShuttingDown = true; SystemEvents.SessionEnding -= handler; };
```

while this does not:

```
SessionEndingEventHandler handler = null;
handler = (sender, e) => { isShuttingDown = true; SystemEvents.SessionEnding -= handler; };
```

In is intuitive that the first statement should cause an error but not immediately clear why the second one is not.

Furthermore, how could I tell if the `SystemEvents.SessionEnding` event has been actually unsubscribed after the call to `handler(null, null)`? The `GetInvocationList` only works with delegates.

```
SystemEvents.SessionEnding += handler;
handler(null, null);
```

Comment: The first statement is more equivalent to `SessionEndingEventHandler handler;`, whereas in the second statement you assign it to null. Its unassigned until the lambda is fully constructed. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362204/how-to-remove-a-lambda-event-handler

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's for the same reason that you'd expect this to fail:

```
int i = 1 - i;
```

The right-hand side of the statement is evaluated before the assignment, and at the time when it's evaluated, the variable hasn't been assigned yet.

In case you think lambdas/delegates change things, consider the following statement:

```
int i = ((Action)() => 1 - i)();
```

Because you're creating the lambda before `i` is assigned, it's *possible* that `i` could be used before any value has been assigned to it. The fact that you don't expect that to happen in your case doesn't change things from the compiler's perspective--you have to explicitly assign a value to the variable before it's used. If it's a null value, then at least the compiler knows you're considering the possibility that it's going to be null when you get to it.

Regarding your final question, a `SessionEndingEventHandler` *is* a delegate. So this would work fine:

```
var unsubscribed = SystemEvents.SessionEnding == null ||
    !SystemEvents.SessionEnding.GetInvocationList().Contains(handler);
```