# Call a method with parameters

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I want to call a method when an animation ends. I'm using this statement:

```
AddHandler anim.Completed, AddressOf anim_completed
```

But i want the anim_completed sub to be with parameters. Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: Just add parameters to the sub...i don't get it.  Also, you're method names need work.  Upper camel case.

Comment: Why would you think i didn't try that? Anyway if i add parameters to the sub i get this:'Public Sub anim_completed(target As Ellipse)' does not have a signature compatible with delegate 'Delegate Sub EventHandler(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)'.

Comment: [Completed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.completed(v=vs.110).aspx) is an event that takes a handler method with a fixed signature. You can't change that.

Comment: So i can't call a method with parameters when an event occurs?

Comment: @Eae --, well, I would think you didn't try that because you didn't say so.  Why didn't you include more pertinent information in your question like "if i add parameters to the sub i get this:'Public Sub anim_completed(target As Ellipse)' does not have a signature compatible with delegate 'Delegate Sub EventHandler(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)'"??

Comment: You're right, my bad :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution. Use Anonymous Event Handler, then you will be able to access Ellipse object directly.

```
Dim target As Ellipse = Nothing

AddHandler anim.Completed, Sub()
                                If target IsNot Nothing Then

                                End If
                            End Sub
```

Comment: `Use Anonymous Event Handler` this is asking for issues when not `Removing` them... There is a thing called `WithEvents` that handles all of this for you, adding and removing handlers...

Comment: Do you need to? :) If you find that you do, then you can find answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362204/how-to-remove-a-lambda-event-handler

Answer (score 0):

Your delegate/method need to have the same signature as the event. But inside that event you can call what ever you want.

```
AddHandler anim.Completed, AddressOf onAnimCompleted

Sub onAnimCompleted(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim target As New Ellipse

    anim_completed(target)

End Sub
```

Comment: But i want to pass an existing ellipse

Comment: @Eae Instead of creating a new Ellipse like in my example, you can get an existing ellipse.