# WPF binding to property of all items in a collection

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, inotifypropertychanged

I need to bind to a bool property, that is only true, when one of the properties in the collection is true.

This is the binding:

```
<tk:BusyIndicator IsBusy="{Binding Tabs, Converter={StaticResource BusyTabsToStateConverter}}">
```

And the viewmodel:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Tab> _tabs;

    public ObservableCollection<Tab> Tabs
    {
        get
        {  return _tabs; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _tabs)
            {
                _tabs = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

The `Tab` class also has property change notification:

```
public class Tab : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public bool IsBusy { get{...} set{...NotifyPropertyChanged();} }
```

This is the converter:

```
public class BusyTabsToStateConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var tabs = value as ObservableCollection<Tab>;
        return tabs.Any(tab => tab.IsBusy);
    }
}
```

The problem is, when `Tab.IsBusy` changes the binding source is not notified, because it is bound to the observable collection and not to the `IsBusy` property.

Is there a way to make the notification trigger correctly when the `IsBusy` property on any of the items in the collection changes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of a Binding Converter, you could have a `AnyTabBusy` property in MainWindowViewModel, for which a change notification is fired by a PropertyChanged event handler, which is attached or detached to individual elements from the `Tabs` collection when they are added to or removed from the collection.

In the example below, the `Tabs` property is readonly. If it has to be writeable, you would have to attach and detach the `TabsCollectionChanged` handler in the Tabs setter.

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ObservableCollection<Tab> Tabs { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Tab>();

    public bool AnyTabBusy
    {
        get { return Tabs.Any(t => t.IsBusy); }
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        Tabs.CollectionChanged += TabsCollectionChanged;
    }

    private void TabsCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Action)
        {
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                foreach (Tab tab in e.NewItems)
                {
                    tab.PropertyChanged += TabPropertyChanged;
                }
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                foreach (Tab tab in e.OldItems)
                {
                    tab.PropertyChanged -= TabPropertyChanged;
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    private void TabPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == nameof(Tab.IsBusy))
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this,
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(AnyTabBusy)));
        }
    }
}
```

---

If you want to make this code reusable, you could put it into a derived collection class like shown below, where you could attach a handler for an `ItemPropertyChanged` event.

```
public class ObservableItemCollection<T>
    : ObservableCollection<T> where T : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler ItemPropertyChanged;

    protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnCollectionChanged(e);

        switch (e.Action)
        {
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                foreach (INotifyPropertyChanged item in e.NewItems)
                {
                    item.PropertyChanged += OnItemPropertyChanged;
                }
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                foreach (INotifyPropertyChanged item in e.OldItems)
                {
                    item.PropertyChanged -= OnItemPropertyChanged;
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    private void OnItemPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ItemPropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, e);
    }
}
```

The view model could now be reduced to this:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ObservableItemCollection<Tab> Tabs { get; }
        = new ObservableItemCollection<Tab>();

    public bool AnyTabBusy
    {
        get { return Tabs.Any(t => t.IsBusy); }
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        Tabs.ItemPropertyChanged += TabPropertyChanged;
    }

    private void TabPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == nameof(Tab.IsBusy))
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(AnyTabBusy)));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The example is great. Although its a lot of code for such little functionality, your solution works great. Thanks!

Comment: @Clemens I hope you don't mind, but I took your answer and [packaged](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46606925/526724) it in to an easy to use extension method.

Comment: @Bradley Of course not, but see also my approach of achieving a more general usage.

Comment: That's a good approach too, and one that I considered also.  I choose the extension method because I plan to add this to my standard WPF library.  That library already has a custom `ObservableCollection` sub-class that supports`AddRange`. I wanted it to be usable on anything that inherits from `ObservableCollection<T>` without needing to have control over the class hierarchy.

Comment: Ok, but don't forget to also add an Unregister method :-)

Answer (score 1):

I've taken @Clemens' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46602612/526724), and converted in to an extension method that could make it easier to use on multiple collections.  It will take an `PropertyChangedEventHandler` and automatically add and remove it from the items in the collection as they are added and removed.  If you up-vote this, please up-vote@Clemens' answer also, since it is based on his work.

Be careful not use use an anonymous method as your `PropertyChanged` handler (this goes for all event handlers in general, not just this solution) without taking special [precautions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362204/how-to-remove-a-lambda-event-handler), as they can be difficult to remove.

(Note: this requires C# 7, as it uses a local function to make dealing with the `CollectionChanged` handler's delegate easier.)

```
public static class ObservableCollectionExtensions
{
    public static Hook<TList> RegisterPropertyChangeHook<TList>(this ObservableCollection<TList> collection, PropertyChangedEventHandler handler) where TList : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        void Collection_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.Action)
            {
                case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                    foreach (TList item in e.NewItems)
                    {
                        item.PropertyChanged += handler;
                    }
                    break;
                case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                    foreach (TList item in e.OldItems)
                    {
                        item.PropertyChanged -= handler;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        return new Hook<TList>(collection, Collection_CollectionChanged);
    }

    public class Hook<TList> where TList : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        internal Hook(ObservableCollection<TList> collection, NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler handler)
        {
            _handler = handler;
            _collection = collection;

            collection.CollectionChanged += handler;
        }

        private NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler _handler;
        private ObservableCollection<TList> _collection;

        public void Unregister()
        {
            _collection.CollectionChanged -= _handler;
        }
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
void Main()
{
    var list = new ObservableCollection<Animal>();

    list.RegisterPropertyChangeHook(OnPropertyChange);

    var animal = new Animal(); // Has a "Name" property that raises PropertyChanged
    list.Add(animal);
    animal.Name="Charlie"; // OnPropertyChange called

    list.Remove(animal);
    animal.Name="Sam"; // OnPropertyChange not called
}

private void OnPropertyChange(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"property changed: {e.PropertyName}");
}
```

If you want to be able to unregister the hook, do this:

```
var hook = list.RegisterPropertyChangeHook(OnPropertyChange);
hook.Unregister();
```

Unregistering ended up being trickier than I expected, due to extension method classes not supporting generics.  It uses the "[memento](http://www.dofactory.com/net/memento-design-pattern)" pattern to return an object that you can use to unregister later.

Answer (score -1):

To propagate notification from Model to Collection of Model, You need to have a Notifiable property in Collection itself.

Maybe you can extend the ObservableCollection and have a Property in that which can notify the UI

Comment: Downvoter needs to specify the reason so that one can rectify any issues.

Answer (score -1):

There's no way to get this for free unfortunately. I would create an IsBusy property on MainWindowViewModel. When Tabs is set, add a listener for collection changes and have that update the IsBusy property.