# Adding and Removing Anonymous Event Handler

Tags: c#, events, anonymous-methods

I was wondering if this actually worked ?

```
private void RegisterKeyChanged(T item) 
{
    item.OnKeyChanged += (o, k) => ChangeItemKey((T)o, k);
}

private void UnRegisterKeyChanged(T item) 
{
    item.OnKeyChanged -= (o, k) => ChangeItemKey((T)o, k);
}
```

How does the compiler know that the event handlers are the same ? Is this even recommended?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unsubscribe anonymous method in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183367/unsubscribe-anonymous-method-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

There's an MSDN page that talks about this:

[How to Subscribe to and Unsubscribe from Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366768.aspx)

Note in particular:

> If you will not have to unsubscribe to [sic]
>   an event later, you can use the
>   addition assignment operator (+=) to
>   attach an anonymous method to the
>   event.

And also:

> It is important to notice that you
>   cannot easily unsubscribe from an
>   event if you used an anonymous
>   function to subscribe to it. To
>   unsubscribe in this scenario, it is
>   necessary to go back to the code where
>   you subscribe to the event, store the
>   anonymous method in a delegate
>   variable, and then add the delegate to
>   the event . In general, we recommend
>   that you do not use anonymous
>   functions to subscribe to events if
>   you will have to unsubscribe from
>   the event at some later point in your
>   code.

Comment: So does it mean, that basically what is in OP doesn't work as supposed to? Does it mean that anonymous delegate, if not stored at subscription point, is almost impossible to unsubscribe?

Comment: @Johnny_D yes, the code that the OP provided does not work. In new versions of IDE's this will give you a compilation warning saying "Event unsubscription via anonymous delegate". When this code executes it will give a runtime error that the event handler that you're trying to unsubscribe from does not exist

Answer (score 25):

For anyone interested, you can add and remove an anonymous event handler like this

```
public class Musician
{
    public void TuneGuitar()
    {
        Metronome metronome = new Metronome();

        EventHandler<EventArgs> handler = null;
        handler = (sender, args) =>
        {
            // Tune guitar
            // ...

            // Unsubscribe from tick event when guitar sound is perfect
            metronome.Tick -= handler;
        };

        // Attach event handler
        metronome.Tick += handler;
    }
}

public class Metronome
{
    event EventHandler<EventArgs> Tick;
}
```

UPDATE:
In C# 7.0 we have supports for [local functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions) so the `TuneGuitar` method can now be written as:

```
public void TuneGuitar()
{
    Metronome metronome = new Metronome();

    void handler(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        // Tune guitar
        // ...

        // Unsubscribe from tick event when guitar sound is perfect
        metronome.Tick -= handler;
    };

    // Attach event handler
    metronome.Tick += handler;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you need to unsubscribe an event handler, you'll need to have a definite reference to a concrete delegate. Looking at [`Delegate.Equality`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.op_equality.aspx) you will find that delegates aren't just compared using reference equality, however this doesn't matter for anonymous delegates.

For an anonymous delegate, the compiler (basically) just creates a new "non-anonymous" delegate for each anonymous delegate, even if the delegate bodies are the same. Because of this, the framework will not find the delegate to unsubscribe when you  use the code example you gave.

Answer (score 3):

That won't work I'm afraid, since the two lambda expressions (and delegates) that you declared are actually different objects, and return different references. Hence, the removal of the handler (`-=`) will always fail.

The common solution to this problem (where you need to remove the handler) is simply to refactor the lamba expression into a proper method. An alternative is to maintain a class variable for the event handler delegate, and add and remove this, though I am personally not a fan of it. (It's more hassle than just creating a normal method, if anything.)

Comment: Note, there is a quite similar question and answer at <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348150/how-do-i-unregister-anonymous-event-handler>, where Reed Copsey suggests the same solution as I do.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe this will work. If you really need to unregister from an event you must specify an explicit event handler which you can later unregister from instead of an anonymous delegate.

Answer (score 1):

If you check with the document for Delegate.Equality, you would find out they are not compared by reference.