# How to remove a method from an Action delegate in C#

Tags: c#, delegates, action

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# Adding and Removing Anonymous Event Handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051357/c-sharp-adding-and-removing-anonymous-event-handler)

suppose I have an Action delegate declared this way:

```
public event Action<MenuTraverser.Actions> menuAction;
```

I am associating a method to it this way:

```
menuInputController.menuAction += (MenuTraverser.Actions action) => this.traverser.OnMenuAction(action);
```

Now, all works fine, but in certain situation I need to remove the delegated method and I don't know how.
I tried this way but doesn't work:

```
menuInputController.menuAction -= (MenuTraverser.Actions action) => this.traverser.OnMenuAction(action);
```

How can I do such a thing? I need that my method OnMenuAction will be no longer called.

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/91778/how-to-remove-all-event-handlers-from-a-control ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your signature seems to match (assuming that you have a `void` return type), you shouldn't need to add an anonymous function but you can use the method group directly:

```
menuInputController.menuAction += this.traverser.OnMenuAction;
```

And in this case unsubscribing should work as well:

```
menuInputController.menuAction -= this.traverser.OnMenuAction;
```

Comment: I would happy if this works, because using @sll 's that works I'm forced to have a chached handler for each method . Anyway it seems not to work for me.

Comment: What do you mean by "seems not to work"? Note that `-=` calls into [`Delegate.Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.remove.aspx), and this will compare delegates using [`Delegate.Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/99bthb1z.aspx), which states this: "Returns true if obj and the current delegate have the same targets, methods, and invocation list" - which is the case in my example but not when you have anonymous methods (which are distinct even if they have the same code in them).

Comment: I mean that if I use your solution then delegate won't be removed. Maybe I'm doing something wrong but simply replacing my code with your, it doesn't. And still I don't understand a thing: Was I using anonymous methods?

Comment: Is `menuAction` using the default event code or does it have custom `add` and `remove` handlers? Because if it has the default handlers my code works. And yes, you were using anonymous methods: `(MenuTraverser.Actions action) => this.traverser.OnMenuAction(action)` is (for this use case - because it doesn't compile to a lamdba-expression) identical to this: `delegate(MenuTraverser.Actions action) { this.traverser.OnMenuAction(action); }` which is an anonymous method.

Comment: Oh..you are right. Your code works (I had a bug). And thanks for the clarification on anonymous method. I was using them without without knowing it. So I was doing the right thing except for having used anonymous methods, right?

Comment: Btw, is there a documentation on the `-=` and `+=` operators for Action delegates? Cannot find it anywhere

Comment: @DataGreed This is a language feature of C#, not a framework feature. Therefore the docs are on the language pages: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/subtraction-operator and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/addition-operator

Answer (score 6):

You need to store a reference to a generic delegate into a field so later you can unsubscribe using this cached delegate field:

```
// declare on a class fields level
Action<MenuTraverser.Action> cachedHandler; 

// in constructor initialize
cachedHandler = (action) => this.traverser.OnMenuAction(action);

// subscribe
menuInputController.menuAction += cachedHandler;

// unsubscribe
menuInputController.menuAction -= cachedHandler;
```