# lambda expression and event handler?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

Someone mentioned to me that c# supports to use lambda expression as event handler, can anyone share with me some reference on this?

A code snippet is preferred.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use a lambda expression to build an anonymous method, which can be attached to an event.

For example, if you make a Windows Form with a `Button` and a `Label`, you could add, in the constructor (after `InitializeComponent()`):

```
 this.button1.Click += (o,e) =>
     {
        this.label1.Text = "You clicked the button!";
     };
```

This will cause the label to change as the button is clicked.

Comment: Yup. I also wanted to point this out regarding adding and removing anonymous event handlers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051357/c-sharp-adding-and-removing-anonymous-event-handler

Comment: @devshorts Yes.  It's not necessarily great if you need to unsubscribe as well.

Comment: Aren't the braces redundant for single-statement method bodies?

Comment: @Superbest They're not necessary for single statement bodies - they don't hurt anything, though, and it makes it a bit more clear when reading in a post like this, which is why I wrote it that way.

Answer (score 0):

try this example

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.button1.Click += new EventHandler(button1_Click);
}

void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

The above event handler can be rewritten using this lambda expression

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.button1.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) = >
    {
        MessageBox.Show(“Button clicked!”);
    };
}
```