# How to create a `Observable` which observes both `Renamed` and `Changed` events from `FileSystemWatcher`

Tags: .net-core, system.reactive, filesystemwatcher

I want to create a `Reactive` `Observable`, which can observe `Renamed` and `Changed` at the same time.

I'm monitoring a folder for modified and renamed files with `FileSystemWatcher`. I only want to handle the event after it has settled down (because sometimes `Changed` event may be raised multiple times). 
So I choose the `Throttle` function of .net's `Reactive Extension`.

I can manage to do the work by observing a single `Changed` event, but can't work out how to observe `Changed` and `Renamed` in a single `Observable`.

Here's what I've done for a single `Changed` event:

```cs
var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
watcher.Path = "d:\\test";
var observable = Observable.FromEventPattern<FileSystemEventHandler, FileSystemEventArgs>(
                            ev => watcher.Changed += ev,
                            ev => watcher.Changed -= ev
);

var d = observable.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
                    .Subscribe(
                        a => Console.WriteLine($"Watcher type:{a.EventArgs.ChangeType }, file:{a.EventArgs.Name }, sender: {a.Sender}"),
                        ex => Console.WriteLine("observer error:" + ex.ToString()),
                        () => Console.WriteLine("observer complete.")
                );
```

But when I want to watch for both the events, VS tells me that `FileSystemEventHandler` and `RenamedEventHandler` are not compatible (though `RenamedEventArgs` can be safely cast to `FileSystemEventArgs`):

```cs
var observable = Observable.FromEventPattern<FileSystemEventHandler, FileSystemEventArgs>(
                            ev => { 
                            watcher.Changed += ev; 
                            //Error
                            watcher.Renamed += ev; 
                            },
                            ev => { 
                            watcher.Changed -= ev; 
                            //Error
                            watcher.Renamed -= ev; 
                            });
```

I know I can convert the `ev` to a compatible delegate , but I'm wondering how can I record that delegate and remove it from the event? Because I read that anonymous delegate can't be removed from `event` unless record it at register time (as described in (this question)[[Adding and Removing Anonymous Event Handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051357/adding-and-removing-anonymous-event-handler])). Aslo, doing it this way same not elegant at all...

```cs
Func<FileSystemEventHandler, RenamedEventHandler> renameDelegate = (FileSystemEventHandler h) =>
                {
                    return (object sender, RenamedEventArgs args) => h(sender, args);
                };
var observable = Observable.FromEventPattern<FileSystemEventHandler, FileSystemEventArgs>(
                            ev => { watcher.Changed += ev; 
                                    //registered delegate
                                    watcher.Renamed += renameDelegate(ev); 
                                    },
                            ev => { watcher.Changed -= ev; 
                                    //this seems not to be identical with the one registered
                                    watcher.Renamed -= renameDelegate(ev); });
                );
```

So how can I observer both `Changed` and `Renamed` event in the same `Observable`?

### EDIT 1

Thanks to @Enigmativity 's answer, my final code goes like below(sample code):

```cs
var o1 = Observable.FromEventPattern<FileSystemEventHandler, FileSystemEventArgs>(
                            ev => watcher.Changed += ev,
                            ev => watcher.Changed -= ev);
var o2 = Observable.FromEventPattern<RenamedEventHandler, RenamedEventArgs>(
                            ev => watcher.Renamed += ev,
                            ev => watcher.Renamed -= ev)
                    .Select(x => new System.Reactive.EventPattern<FileSystemEventArgs>(x.Sender, x.EventArgs));

var o = Observable.Merge(o1, o2);

var d = o.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
                    .Subscribe(
                        a => Console.WriteLine($"Watcher type:{a.EventArgs.ChangeType }, file:{a.EventArgs.Name }, sender: {a.Sender}"),
                        ex => Console.WriteLine("observer error:" + ex.ToString()),
                        () => Console.WriteLine("observer complete.")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how you do it:

```
var observable =
    Observable
        .Using(
            () => new FileSystemWatcher() { Path = "d:\\test" },
            watcher =>
                Observable
                    .Merge(
                        Observable
                            .FromEventPattern<FileSystemEventHandler, FileSystemEventArgs>(
                                ev => watcher.Changed += ev,
                                ev => watcher.Changed -= ev)
                            .Select(x => new
                            {
                                x.EventArgs.Name,
                                x.EventArgs.FullPath,
                                x.EventArgs.ChangeType,
                                OldName = (string)null,
                                OldFullPath = (string)null,
                            }),
                        Observable
                            .FromEventPattern<RenamedEventHandler, RenamedEventArgs>(
                                ev => watcher.Renamed += ev,
                                ev => watcher.Renamed -= ev)
                            .Select(x => new
                            {
                                x.EventArgs.Name,
                                x.EventArgs.FullPath,
                                x.EventArgs.ChangeType,
                                x.EventArgs.OldName,
                                x.EventArgs.OldFullPath
                            })));
```

Comment: Got it, so the key here is to use `Merge`. Thank you!