# Removing a Delegate from an Event Inside a Task's Continuation Method

Tags: c#, winforms, delegates, task, task-parallel-library

I have a 'stop process button' `ToolStripButton` on a parent MDI form. From a child form I start a process on a background thread using TPL, and get the tasks return status and changes the UI accordingly. The `Click` event of the 'stop process button' is dealt with using a `delegate` which works well. However, I cannot seem to remove it. Please see the code below:

```
private void buttonRunValid_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // UI.
    mainForm.stopButton.Enabled = true;

    // Thread cancellation.
    cancelSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    token = cancelSource.Token;

    // Start new parallel task and pass uiScheduler.
    Task<bool> asyncValidationTask = new Task<bool>(state => 
        asyncRunValidationProcess(uiScheduler, token, ref timeSpan), 
            "Running Validation Process");
    asyncValidationTask.Start();

    // Callback for cancellation.
    asyncValidationTask.ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        // Do some error checking with task.Status...

        // Remove delegate (back on uiThread).
        mainForm.stopButton.Click -= delegate
            {
                UtilsTPL.CancelRunningProcess(ref mainForm, asyncValidationTask, cancelSource); 
            };
        return;
    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

    // Handle the cancellation.
    mainForm.stopButton.Click += delegate 
        { 
            UtilsTPL.CancelRunningProcess(ref mainForm, asyncValidationTask, cancelSource);
        };
    return;
}
```

where `mainForm` is the `MdiParent` and `stopButton` is an accessor to the `mainForm`'s `ToolStripButton` which fires the cancel/stop process event.

I am attempting to remove the `delegate` in the tasks continuation method but this is not working. I have also tried to loop through all events contained by the `ToolStripButton` using reflection:

```
FieldInfo fieldInfo = 
    typeof(Control).GetField("EventClick", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic); 
object obj = fieldInfo.GetValue(_stripButton); 
PropertyInfo propertyInfo = 
    _stripButton.GetType().GetProperty("Events", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance); 
EventHandlerList list = (EventHandlerList)propertyInfo.GetValue(_stripButton, null); 
list.RemoveHandler(obj, list[obj]);
```

This also does not work. How can I remove the `EventHandler`/`delegate`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using anonymous methods or lambdas for event handlers is problematic for this reason. The delegate you're adding and the one you're trying to remove are different instances (despite containing identical code). The solution *to this problem* is either to save a reference to the delegate you're adding, or to use a named method instead. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348150/how-do-i-unregister-anonymous-event-handler) for details.

However, I'd ask why you're removing the event handler in the first place. If it's to stop your handler code from running while a particular process is in progress, I'd prefer disabling the button, then re-enabling it once processing has finished.

Comment: The `MdiParent` contains a `ToolStrip` that hosts a generic stop button. I have many processes that run with dirrerent `Task`s and this button is to be used to stop any of them according to which `Task` is passed to the cancel method/delegate.