# Unsubscribe events vis anonymous delegate

Tags: c#, .net, events, delegates, closures

I want to know how to unsubscribe anonymous methods from the events.

I have already checked [Unsubscribe anonymous method in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183367/unsubscribe-anonymous-method-in-c-sharp) but my case is little different.

I am accessing local function variable  in the anonymous method.

Code is as below

```
 private static void Test(Object dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    {
        if (dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs.OldValue is ObservableCollection<object>)
        {
            (dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs.OldValue as ObservableCollection<object>).CollectionChanged -=
                (s, e) => SelectedItemsChanged(dependencyObject, e); // TO FIX event unbsubscription via anonymous delegate
        }

        if (dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs.NewValue is ObservableCollection<object>)
        {
            (dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs.NewValue as ObservableCollection<object>).CollectionChanged +=
                (s, e) => SelectedItemsChanged(dependencyObject, e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: In what way is your case different? You simply can't do this - it won't work. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348150/how-do-i-unregister-anonymous-event-handler too.

Comment: difference is that i need to provide access of variable local to function. How to pass this variable, if i choose to use named method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**New answer, now the question has changed**

You can't, basically. Your handler depends on `dependencyObject`, which will be captured in a new object on each call, so you'll end up with unequal delegates.

You could create a new class which holds the dependency object *and overrides `Equals` to compare those objects* instead of using anonymous functions, or you could just hold a reference to the previously-subscribed handler.

---

**Old answer, when the delegate didn't depend on the parameters**

The bizarre thing is that in this particular case, it looks like you're not capturing any local variables. So it's *possible* that if the *only* place you're subscribing to the event is from this method, you could get away with:

```
private static void Test(Object a, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{
    NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler handler = 
        (s, e) => SelectedItemsChanged(dependencyObject, e);

    var oldObservable = args.OldValue as ObservableCollection<object>;
    if (oldObservable != null)
    {
        oldObservable.CollectionChanged -= handler;
    }
    var newObservable = args.NewValue as ObservableCollection<object>;
    if (newObservable != null)
    {
        newObservable.CollectionChanged += handler;
    }
}
```

As you've only got *one* lambda expression now, I'd expect that to be converted into a single static method, so the freshly-created delegate will be equal to the original one.

However, I wouldn't *recommend* that. I'd just create the method yourself, and then use a method group conversion.

Comment: There was typo in my question. First parameter should be dependencyObject (not a). How to use method group conversion (and pass dependencyObject to the method)?

Comment: @Tilak: In that case, you can't, and you should store the handler instead. I'll edit.

Comment: @Tilak: In future, please don't edit my answers when the change makes a significant difference to the meaning. The result was code that *wouldn't* have worked, and which didn't gel with my description either.

Comment: @JonSkeet are you sure this will remove the same handler that was added in a previous iteration? I'm expecting unpredictable results here. Or does this works because there's no captured variable ?

Comment: @StephaneDelcroix: I *believe* it would be okay because it's not capturing anything - but that only worked when `dependencyObject` wasn't a parameter, so it wasn't clear where that was coming from anyway. If it were an instance variable, I believe it would end up with a delegate targeting an instance method, and any two such delegates with the same target object would be equal.

Answer (score 2):

You *can not* do that with anonymous delegates. 
In order to be able to *unsubscribe* you have to use *usual* delegates.