# Un Registering short hand / Inline events in C#

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I Unregister ‘anonymous’ event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348150/how-do-i-unregister-anonymous-event-handler)

In my c# method i am using

```
this.Loaded+=(sender,e)=>{ my code };
```

for executing the code on load time. But my issue is that i don't how to un register this chained events. I tried something similar to

```
this.Loaded-=(sx,ex)=>{};
```

but the event is not un registering. Any one please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code creates anonymous type with method that is attached to event so to detach form this event you need to provide the same method not a new one.

so try this:

```
EventHandler handler = (sender,e)=>{...};
Loaded += handler;
Loaded -= handler;
```

Thow for attaching to `this.` event there usually is nice alternative like

```
override OnLoaded(EventArgs args)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can not *unregister* inline event subscription. If you want to have a possibility to *unregister*, use a usual `delegate/handler` subscription.