# ListBox TwoWay bind to SelectedItem

Tags: wpf, data-binding, listbox, selecteditem, two-way-binding

I've seen this question asked numerous times and have gone over my code over and over.  But when I assign to my `SelectedItem`-bound property with an object, it does not update the display's selected item.  It appears that the `ListBox` thinks the object I assign is not a member of its items.

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    //...
    public SortedObservableCollection<TubeViewModel> Items { get; private set; }
    public TubeViewModel SelectedTube { //get, set, propertychanged, etc. }
}

<ListBox x:Name="TubeList"
         Margin="10"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TubeTemplate}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTube, Mode=TwoWay}" 
         SelectionMode="Single"
         VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False">
</ListBox>
```

Here's the impl from one of the places where I try to set `SelectedTube` - definitely occurs on the main thread.

```
 var match =
    from t in Items
    where t.Model.DataFileName == filename
    select t;
 if (match.Any())
    SelectedTube = match.First();
```

I was noticing that the `SelectedTube` was never highlighted unless I manually clicked on it, but kind of ignored it.  But then I wanted to [ScrollIntoViewCentered](http://blogs.msdn.com/delay/archive/2009/04/19/fewer-gotchas-to-getcha-enhancing-the-scrollintoviewcentered-method-for-wpf-s-listbox.aspx) the selected item, so I added a `DependencyProperty` in my view to watch for `SelectedItem` changes.  The handler initially looked like so:

```
private void OnSelectedItemChanged(DependencyObject target, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (TubeList.SelectedItem == null)
       return;

    TubeList.ScrollIntoViewCentered(TubeList.SelectedItem);
}
```

But didn't work if I set the `SelectedItem` through my binding.  After deciding I wanted to only scroll it if it was not on screen, I changed the code to this:

```
private void OnSelectedItemChanged(DependencyObject target, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (TubeList.SelectedItem == null)
       return;

    var container = TubeList.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(TubeList.SelectedItem) as FrameworkElement;

    if(!container.IsVisible)
       TubeList.ScrollIntoViewCentered(TubeList.SelectedItem);
}
```

If `SelectedItem` is externally set, container is null.  Every time.  I even added code to check for null and then iterate over the `ItemsSource` looking for a filename match, then update `SelectedItem` to make sure `SelectedItem` was definitely an object in the listbox.  No luck.

It's not a visibility thing, if the item is on screen, it still doesn't highlight.  Do I need to implement some sort of equality function?  I've wasted more time than one might think possible on this.

thanks.

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce this with what we see of your code.  I made a dummy class for TubeViewModel and used all of your posted code and it worked as expected.  Something must be going on elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Ben and Kent.  I'm off on vacation for a while, this will have to wait.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this is also related to the fact that `ItemContainerGenerators` are generated in a separate thread... ([at least in the TreeView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905995/wpf-select-treeviewitem-broken-past-the-root-level/1927293#1927293))

Try calling UpdateLayout() before you ask the `ItemContainerGenerators` property.

Comment: I don't get why this is necessary, but I'm happy it is.  Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing jumps out at me as obviously wrong, but you've glossed over a lot. I can only suggest you simplify things until you either find the problem, or have a complete non-working example that you can post.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried checking the hashcode of each object in the itemsource against the hashcode of the object you are trying to set? The Linq query will return something different.

As a test trying setting the SelectedTube to Items[0].