# Removing anonymous event handler

Tags: c#, wcf

I have the following code where SprintServiceClient is a reference to a WCF Service-

```
public class OnlineService
{
    private SprintServiceClient _client;
    public OnlineService()
    {
        _client = new SprintServiceClient();
    }

    public void AddMemberToTeam(MemberModel user, int projectId, Action<int> callback)
    {
        _client.AddMemberToTeamCompleted += (s, e) => callback(e.Result);
        _client.AddMemberToTeamAsync(user.ToUser(), projectId);
    }
}
```

the problem is that every time AddMemberToTeam is called it adds another callback to client.AddMemberToTeamCompleted

i.e the first time AddMemberToTeam is called the callback is called once, the second time AddMemberToTeam is called the callback is called twice ect.

Is there any way to remove the eventhandler from AddMemberToTeamCompleted once the eventhandler has been called or use another method which takes in the callback?

Comment: To remove it, you need a reference. Assuming the "AddMemberToTeamCompleted" is defined with the 'event' keyword (leaving only the -= and += operators), you will have to maintain a variable with the delegate instance. Create and add it on first time, don't add any next time, remove on close-down.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unsubscribe anonymous method in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183367/unsubscribe-anonymous-method-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can refer to your anonymous method from inside itself as long as you assign a delegate to a variable first:

```
EventHandler<SomeEventArgs> handler = null;
handler = (s, e) =>
    {
        _client.AddMemberToTeamCompleted -= handler;
        callback(e.Result);
    };

_client.AddMemberToTeamCompleted += handler;
```

Note that you need to declare the variable and assign it separately or the compiler will deem it uninitialized when you come to use it inside the method body.

Answer (score 19):

The trick to making a self-unsubscribing event-handler is to capture the *handler itself* so you can use it in a `-=`. There is a problem of *declaration* and *definite assignment*, though; so we **can't** do something like:

```
EventHandler handler = (s, e) => {
    callback(e.Result);
    _client.AddMemberToTeamCompleted -= handler; // <===== not yet defined     
};
```

So instead we initialize to `null` first, so the declaration is *before* the usage, and it has a known value (`null`) before first used:

```
EventHandler handler = null;
handler = (s, e) => {
    callback(e.Result);
    _client.AddMemberToTeamCompleted -= handler;        
};
_client.AddMemberToTeamCompleted += handler;
```

Comment: I seem to be missing something here... Can someone please explain why handler is not null when its value is captured upon the creation of the delegate to the anonymous method? Isn't the right-hand side of an assignment operator processed first? So, shouldn't the capture of the value of handler occur *before* handler gets assigned to the new anonymous delegate? Yet, this code seems to work, so I'm curious why it's working rather than trying to remove a null handler. Does the value capture of outer variables in the anonymous method somehow occur after the assignment of handler?

Comment: @reirab in c#, it is the variable that is captured - not the current value.

Comment: Ah, ok, thanks. I was aware that the C# compiler actually creates a new object that included the anonymous method and the variable being captured, however, I didn't previously realize that the variable in the new object is actually the one used by the outer class, not just a copy of it. Interesting.

Answer (score 2):

<s>No there is no way,</s>

Apparantly Tim and Marc have another nice solution

But you can always just name them, and do the `-=` on the named eventhandler on this method ;)

Guessing your event:

```
_client.AddMemberToTeamCompleted += OnAddMemberToTeamCompleted;
```

and

```
public void OnAddMemberToTeamCompleted(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    _client.AddMemberToTeamCompleted -= OnAddMemberToTeamCompleted;
    callback(e.Result)
}
```

Next problem is getting this callback in your listener. Perhaps putting it on a Property in the EventArgs (but that feels kinda dirty, I agree)