# Detaching a null event handler

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, event-handling

I've been commissioned with cleaning up memory leaks in our code as well as placing checks to prevent further leaks.  I've noticed un-detached handlers seem to be the main cause.  Most are straight forward, but there are a couple things in code that have made me scratch my head.

First:

`myObject.someEvent -= null;`

Am I correct in assuming that does absolutely nothing?  (I know that if an event is local you can set it to null since it's essentially a multicast delegate).

Second, for anonymous handlers:

`myObject.someEvent += ()=> { x + y; };

myObject.someEvent -= ()=> { x + y; };`

Am I correct in saying the second instruction is worthless as well since the anonymous methods will be compiled as two separate delegates and therefore the subtraction doesn't actually point to the correct handler that would need to be removed?  (For anyone looking for a proper solution to solve this, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4303966/1265219)).

I don't want to settle for "yeah, that's right", I want to know **why** these things don't work (assuming my assertions are correct).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case we can see from the decompiled implementation of `MulticastDelegate.CombineImpl` (use IL Spy or something) that if the delegate passed in is `null` then no combining is done - so yes, removing a null delegate does nothing.

---

In the second case it all depends on whether or not the compiler considers the two lambda expressions to be equal.  This exact question is indirectly answered in [this blog article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/06/18/implementation-defined-behaviour.aspx)

> in C# if you have:
>
> ```
> Func<int, int> f1 = (int x)=>x + 1;
> Func<int, int> f2 = (int x)=>x + 1;
> bool b = object.ReferenceEquals(f1, f2);
> ```
>
> *<< snip >>* **In C# this is therefore left to be implementation-defined**; a compiler
>   can choose to make them reference equal or not at its discretion.

You can work out whether or not the current C# compiler considers these two to be equal or not fairly easily however thats not really the point - this is implementation defined behaviour and shouldn't be relied on.

Comment: That's really interesting, I never realized you could define implementations in this way.  Thanks!

Comment: @Devin By "Implementation-defined", I mean defined by the implementation of the compiler - you (as the application author) cannot define this implementation, you are stuck with whatever the compiler chooses to do.

Answer (score 3):

From the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366768.aspx):

> It is important to notice that you cannot easily unsubscribe from an event if you used an anonymous function to subscribe to it. To unsubscribe in this scenario, it is necessary to go back to the code where you subscribe to the event, store the anonymous method in a delegate variable, and then add the delegate to the event . In general, we recommend that you do not use anonymous functions to subscribe to events if you will have to unsubscribe from the event at some later point in your code.

So you are correct, you cannot remove the anonymous method like that. In a similar way, saying  `myObject.someEvent -= null;` will also do nothing

Comment: The issue with unsubscribing from them is actually that they are handled *the same*. Without a variable pointing to the anonymous method the compiler behavior for determining equality of a new anonymous function is undefined as @Justin pointed out. Meaning that the removal will not know that the anonymous method contained by the handler is the same as that which it is attempting to remove.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that even *adding* doesn't matter :

```
public Action  del;
void Main()
{

del+=(()=>"1".Dump());

 del+=null;
 del+=null;
 del+=null; 

del+=(()=>"2".Dump());
del();
del.GetInvocationList().Select(f=>f.Target);

}



//ouput:
1
2
```

Answer (score 0):

> second instruction is worthless as well since the anonymous methods will be compiled as two separate delegates and therefore the subtraction doesn't actually point to the correct handler that would need to be removed?

Correct. Each lambda creates a new delegate object, which will not be equal to the first.

And I would expect the first to throw if it isn;t a no-op (I can't see how it could do anything useful.)