# C# how to remove delegation

Tags: c#, delegation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unsubscribe anonymous method in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183367/unsubscribe-anonymous-method-in-c)

I have some Panels that when created they are delegated to become clickable:

```
int z2 = z;
PicBx[z].Click += delegate { clicked(z2, null); };
```

I want to be able to remove this if the program calls for it. I tried using:

```
int z2 = z;
PicBx[z].Click -= delegate { clicked(z2, null); };
```

But it didn't work. Is there any way to remove the clickable delegation from it?

Comment: Why would you need this?

Answer (score 11):

You can't unsubscribe from anonymous delegate, you need to keep reference to delegate

```
var myClickDelegate = (RoutedEventHandler)delegate { clicked(z2, null); };

PicBx[z].Click += myClickDelegate;

...

PicBx[z].Click -= myClickDelegate;
```

Or create named function

Hope this helps

Comment: Im getting "Cannot assign anonymous method to an implicitly-typed local variable" when using `var myClickDelegate = delegate { clicked(z2, null); };`

Comment: try edited post, add (RoutedEventHandler) type converter

Comment: This didn't work. On the program you can select a panel and remove it which changes the order. For some reason its keeping the delegation order of the panels after removal. Right now I'm just trying to remove all the delegation from all the panels after removal of one, to test for now.

Comment: I just test it in a simple application, it works fine, check you business