# Multi-Cast Delegate Subscribe/Unsubscribe to Button Click Event

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, delegates, event-handling

I want to subscribe and unsubscribe from a `ToolStripButton`'s `Click` event using a globally declared delegate as discribed [in this SO question and subsequent answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183367/unsubscribe-anonymous-method-in-c-sharp). I have the following delegate declared globally in my class

```
private delegate void StopTask(ref MainForm _mainForm, 
    Task _task, CancellationTokenSource _cancelSource);
```

I then set this delegate to hold a method as follows

```
StopTask cancelTask = UtilsTPL.CancelRunningProcess;
```

where in the public class `UtilsTPL`, `CancelRunningProcess` is defined as

```
public static void CancelRunningProcess(ref MainForm _mainForm, Task _task, 
    CancellationTokenSource _cancelSource)
{
    // Some really amazing code...
}
```

I then try to add the delegate to my `ToolStripButton` click event like this (and also unsubscribe as shown)

```
mainForm.stopButton.Click += cancelTask;
mainForm.stopButton.Click -= cancelTask;
```

This clearly does not work, as there is a glaring type miss-match.

How do I subscribe/unsubscribe the consistant delegate `cancelTask` to the buttons click event? Thanks for your time.

Note: I am doing this so that the button can be reused for the cancellation of many different `Task`s.

Comment: Events are tied to a specific type of delegate: in `Click`'s case, it's a basic `EventHandler`, i.e. an `Action<object, EventArgs>`, not an `Action<ref MainForm, Task, CancellationTokenSource>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of subscribing and unsubscribing from the click event, call your `cancelTask` from your click-event

```
private void stopButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var handler = cancelTask;
    if (handler != null) {
        handler(this, _task, _cancelSource);
    }
}
```

and subscribe and unsubscribe from `cancelTask`

```
cancelTask += Whatever;
cancelTask -= Whatever;
```

Comment: This should be `handler(ref this, _task, _cancelSource)` to match the delegate type, and typing `ref this` sends shivers down my spine.

Comment: Yes, the MainForm is a reference type; therefore, the argument should probably not be `ref` anyway. Probably it would not work with multicast delegates either.

Comment: So you are saying that this would not work? I can't see the wood-for-the-trees at the moment - it has been a long day. Any further suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: A `ref` parameter means that a reference to the original variable is passed to the method. The method can therefore change the value of this original variable (not just the properties of an object referenced by this variable). With a multicast delegate, multiple methods can be "attached" to the delegate and therefore multiple methods could try to change the value of this single variable. Which one of them would win? And by the way, what would happen if you changed `this` (see  Frédéric Hamidi's comment)?

Comment: If you pass MainForm as parameter to a method, this method can change public properties of MainForm, even if the parameter is not a `ref` parameter. Because the form is a reference type, a reference is passed anyway. With `ref`, a reference to this reference would be passed, which is probably not what you intended.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be a bit more curious about what you are trying to accomplish.  Perhaps there is a way to do things without using a global multi-cast delegate.

Comment: I state this at the bootom of the question. Thanks.