# Unsubscribe lambda expression from event c#

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, lambda

I have the following code attaching event handler:

```
this.btnOK.Click += (s,e) => { MessageBox.Show("test");  };
```

Can I unsubscribe that lambda expression from the vent?

Comment: You can't unsubscribe anonymous function because it is anonymous and you can't access it. Possible solution you can find on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9745280/how-to-unsubscribe-an-anonymous-function-in-dispose-method-of-a-class. You cant unsubscribe anonoy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why don't just ***save*** the assigned lambda?

```
 EventHandler lambda = (s,e) => { MessageBox.Show("test");  };

 ...

 this.btnOK.Click += lambda;

 ... 

 this.btnOK.Click -= lambda;
```

Comment: Ugh, nothing worse than pressing the Enter key by mistake.

Answer (score -2):

You cannot `un-assign that event` because it is a `anonymous method`.

Give it a name and you are ready to unsubscribe.

Answer (score -3):

you can do :

```
this.btnOK.Click = null;
```

Comment: But this would cause all the `subscribed events` to go to drain

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed., this can cause only the compiler error.

Comment: yes, my solution delete all subscriptions. the solution proposed by @Dmitry Bychenko is much better

Comment: @Bob, you "solution" doing nothing except causing compiler error.