# C# - SignalR How can I remove my event handler

Tags: c#, delegates, xamarin.ios, signalr, xamarin

I am a C# newbie trying to implement SignalR in my Xamarin IOS app.

My code is quite simple:

```
 _connection = new Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Hubs.HubConnection (Common.signalRAddress);

feedHub = _connection.CreateHubProxy ("feedHub");

_connection.Received += data =>  { OnReceiveData (data); };

_connection.Start ();
```

my question is how can I remove my delegate?
Is it enough to write?

```
_connection.Received -= data =>  { OnReceiveData (data); };
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Yes. That is how you remove a delegate!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unsubscribe anonymous method in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183367/unsubscribe-anonymous-method-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I might be wrong, but if you do that it won't actually unsubscribe the event.

It didn't in a little test app I wrote anyways.

Instead create a function such as

```
void Connection_Recieved(string obj)
{
}
```

and do connection.Recieved += Connection_Recieved;
and    connection.Recieved -= Connection_Recieved;

I don't think anonymous event functions are the way to go here :)

I am assuming, looking at your code sample you could just do,

```
   connection.Recieved += OnReceiveData;
   connection.Recieved -= OnReceiveData;
```

Answer (score 15):

You're using a hub, why not use the built in on/off for method invocations?

aka:

```
var doSomething = feeHub.On<int>("doSomething", val => {
    // Do something with int val
});
```

Then to remove it you can do:

```
doSomething.Dispose();
```

If you truly want to listen to ALL data that flows through the hub then using Received is the correct approach and @Dracanus' answer will work.