# Use "this" referring anonymous delegate

Tags: c#, delegates

How to use the `this` (or something of that kind) referring to the delegate instance instead of the class instance ?

```
instance.OnEventFoo += delegate()
    {
        if (condition)
        {
            instance.OnEventBar += this;
        }
    };
```

Comment: Does the `RowChanged` event pass inn `sender, e`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183367/unsubscribe-anonymous-method-in-c-sharp

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen yes but it does not matter for the example :)

Comment: @Vladim Thx but the question is "how to refer to this" and not "how to remove a delegate"

Comment: No, I misread your question, so never mind me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you can't refer to a variable before it is declared, you have to:

1. first declare the variable,
2. then assign a delegate,
3. then register the handler with the event.

---

```
// Add an anonymous delegate to the events list and auto-removes automatically if item disposed
DataRowChangeEventHandler handler = null;
handler = (sender, args) =>
    {
        if (condition)
        {
            // need to remove this delegate instance of the events list
            RowChanged -= handler;
        }
    };

something.RowChanged += handler;
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to store it in a variable somewhere. For example:

```
EventHandler rowChanged = null; // to avoid "uninitialized variable" error

rowChanged = (s, e) =>
{
    if (condition)
    {
        // this will unsubscribe from the event as expected
        RowChanged -= rowChanged;
    }
};
```

Comment: Aren't they any way to avoid use of a new var ?

Comment: @56ka No. You need a delegate that references itself. And since you can't refer to a variable before it is declared, you need to declare it first.

Comment: @56ka: No, but why would that bother you?

Comment: Because I like to know small details and tricks of languages I use ;)