# Why can't I unsubscribe from an Event Using a Lambda Expression?

Tags: c#, lambda

This article states [You Can’t Unsubscribe from an Event Using a Lambda Expression](http://csharp.2000things.com/2014/08/28/1170-you-cant-unsubscribe-from-an-event-using-a-lambda-expression/).

E.g. you can subscribe as follows:

```
d.Barked += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine("Bark: {0}", e);
```

but you can't unsubscribe like this:

```
d.Barked -= (s, e) => Console.WriteLine("Bark: {0}", e);
```

Why? What's the difference between this and unsubscribing from a delegate, e.g.

```
EventHandler<string> handler = (s, e) => Console.WriteLine("Bark: {0}", e);
d.Barked += handler;

// ...

d.Barked -= handler;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183367/unsubscribe-anonymous-method-in-c-sharp

Comment: Yes, this outlines the same as what's in the article but it doesn't explain why.

Comment: @TimSchmelter unfortunately my browser can only see into the past.

Comment: I specifically asked "why" and included an example of "how" in the question. Doesn't that imply that I'm looking to have the "why" explained?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

It all comes down to: when are two delegates considered the same for the purposes of delegate addition / subtraction. When you unsubscribe, it is essentially using the logic from `Delegate.Remove`, which considers two delegates equivalent if both the `.Target` and the `.Method` match (at least, for the simple case of a delegate with a single target method; multicast is more complicated to describe). So: what is the `.Method` and `.Target` on a lambda (assuming we are compiling it to a *delegate*, and not to an *expression*)?

The compiler actually has a lot of freedom here, but what *happens* is:

- if the lambda includes a closure over a parameter or variable, the compiler creates a method  (the *method*) on a compiler-generated class that represents the capture-context (which can also include the `this` token); the *target* is the reference to this capture-context instance (which will be defined by the capture scope)
- if the lambda doesn't include a closure over a parameter or variable, but does make use of per-instance state via `this` (implicit or explicit), the compiler creates an instance method  (the *method*) on the current type; the *target* is the current instance (`this`)
- otherwise the compiler creates a static method (the *method*), and the *target* is null (incidentally, in this scenario it also includes a nifty field to cache a single static delegate instance - so *in this scenario*, only one delegate is ever created per lambda)

What it **doesn't** do, however, is compare lots of lambdas with similar looking bodies to reduce any. So what I get when I compile your code is **two** static methods:

```
[CompilerGenerated]
private static void <Main>b__0(object s, string e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Bark: {0}", e);
}

[CompilerGenerated]
private static void <Main>b__2(object s, string e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Bark: {0}", e);
}
```

(the `Main` here is just because in my test rig those lambdas are inside the `Main` method - but ultimately the compiler can choose any unpronounceable names it chooses here)

The first method is used by the first lambda; the second method is used by the second lambda. So ultimately, the reason it doesn't work is because the `.Method` doesn't match.

In regular C# terms, it would be like doing:

```
obj.SomeEvent += MethodOne;
obj.SomeEvent -= MethodTwo;
```

where `MethodOne` and `MethodTwo` have the same code inside them; it doesn't unsubscribe anything.

It might be *nice* if the compiler spotted this, but it is **not required to**, and as such it is safer that it doesn't *elect* to - it could mean that different compilers start producing very different results.

As a side note; it could be very confusing if it *did* try to de-dup, because you'd also have the issue of capture contexts - it would then be the case that it "worked" in some cases and not others - without being obvious which - probably the worst possible scenario.