# Prism EventAggregator Subscribe to delegate that references itself to Unsubscribe

Tags: c#, delegates, prism, eventaggregator

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
EventHandler handler = null;
handler = (s, args) =>
{
    DoStuff();
    something.SomeEvent -= handler;
};
something.SomeEvent += handler;
```

with Prism's EventAggregator?
ie

```
Action subscriber = null;
subscriber = () =>
{
    DoStuff();
    EventAggregator.GetEvent<SomeEvent>().Unsubscribe(subscriber);
};
EventAggregator.GetEvent<SomeEvent>().Subscribe(subscriber);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that will work with Prism's event aggregator, too. It all comes down to comparing delegates for equality in both examples. Refering to a delegate inside of the anyonymous method is not specific to the event aggregator.

However, you should be aware that while using anonymous methods for this kind of one-time event handling is working, because you hold on to the delegate instance `handler` or `subscriber`, subscribing to and unsubscribing from anonymous methods can be quite challenging in more complex scenarios. You should have have a look at these two questions for understanding how delegate comparison works for anonymous methods.

- [How to remove a lambda event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362204/how-to-remove-a-lambda-event-handler)
- [Why can't I unsubscribe from an Event Using a Lambda Expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25563518/why-cant-i-unsubscribe-from-an-event-using-a-lambda-expression/25564492)

As alternatives to using an anonymous method, you could either use instance methods or [local functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions) that were introduced in *C# 7.0*, like in the following example.

```
private void AddEventHandler()
{
   // Local method to replace your anonymous method
   void DoStuffAndUnsubscribe()
   {
      DoStuff();
      eventAggregator.GetEvent<SomeEvent>().Unsubscribe(DoStuffAndUnsubscribe);
   }

   eventAggregator.GetEvent<SomeEvent>().Subscribe(DoStuffAndUnsubscribe);
}
```

As @Haukinger pointed out, the most concise way is to capture an instance of the subscription token of the event in the anonymous method to unsubscribe using `Dispose()`.

```
IDisposable subscriptionToken = null;
subscriptionToken = eventAggregator.GetEvent<SomeEvent>().Subscribe(() =>
{
    DoStuff();
    subscriptionToken.Dispose();
});
```

Comment: This is overly complicated, you can just dispose the subscription (the value returned from `Subscribe`) to unsubscribe.

Comment: Thanks, I thought of subscription tokens, but missed capturing them in a lambda. Have an upvote.

Comment: I've noticed that local functions can only access value-types from the containing method, not reference type.

Is that how it's supposed to work or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: @JamesDePaola I have tested all of the above methods to ensure that they are working. A local function can capture instance state, method arguments or local variables, it should not be restricted to value types only. Just try to create a local `object` and refer to it in the local method, that should work just fine.

Comment: @thatguy  This is what I'm using:


```int x = 1;
object y = new TextBox();

IDisposable subscriptionToken = null;
subscriptionToken = this.EventAggregator.GetEvent<DataObjectIDSelectedEvent>().Subscribe((args) =>
            {
                //x = 6;
                //y = new CheckBox();
                System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
                //subscriptionToken.Dispose();
            });```


Once I uncomment any of those lines, even just "x=6;", the anonymous method is simply never called.

Comment: @thatguy And that's just for anonymous method. I only got local method to work using a work around. Cause this:


          ```SubscriptionToken token = null;
            token=  this.EventAggregator.GetEvent<DataObjectIDSelectedEvent>().Subscribe(LocalMethod);

            void LocalMethod(SelectedDataObjectIDArgs args)
            {
                this.EventAggregator.GetEvent<DataObjectIDSelectedEvent>().Unsubscribe(token);```
while it compiles, it never gets called.

Answer (score 1):

`Subscribe` returns a subscription object which you can dispose to unsubscribe:

```
IDisposable subscription = null;
subscription = eventAggregator.GetEvent<SomeEvent>().Subscribe( () =>
                                                                {
                                                                    // do something
                                                                    subscription.Dispose();
                                                                } );
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing; but so long as an object declared outside the anonymous method is within that method, the method is never called. So I'm at a loss why it's not working for me.

I even copied your code into mine. The anonymous method doesn't get called until I comment out the line referencing "subscription"