# Can I safely remove unused parameters from Web page event handlers and why are parameters in Page_Load not unused?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, suppress-warnings

In order to be a neat programmer I try to fix the build warnings. But I get stuck with the warnings for unused parameters in page event handlers. Example:

```
public partial class MyPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        some code not referencing sender or e
    }
```

If I would follow upon the recommendation of VisualStudio and remove the unused parameters `sender` and `e`, I would alter the method signature and the code might not work correctly. However, according to [this microsoft help page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182268.aspx) the signature for event handlers does not look at the parameters. The language of that page is confusing to me, with jargon like `breaking`, but in this case I guess that it is indeed safe to remove the unused parameters.

But how about the next event handler, where the arguments are also not used, but VisualStudio does NOT issue the same warning:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack && !IsCallback)
        InitPagina();
    return;
}
```

My questions are:

- Are these parameters really unused and unneeded?
- What is meant with the term `breaking` in the help page?
- What is different between the event handler types for Page_PreInit and Page_Load?
- Do unused parameters really incur maintenance and performance costs, as the help page states?
- Should it perhaps be best practice to suppress the Unused Parameters warnings?

Comment: If I read the Microsoft help page you referenced correctly, you should not be getting the warning anyway.  It says under "Causes" that it does not examine parameters of methods used as EventHandlers.  I just leave the default parameters in on code-behind EH's.  When the parameters are not needed, at least when someone comes back later, they will know what parameters were available.

Comment: @MichaelGorsich Indeed. I would rather think that removing those 'unneeded' parameters incur maintenance and performance costs in case these are needed later. Ergo: better suppress these build warnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own questions, in order:

- These parameters may be needed later, so are not really "unneeded" (see comment by Michael Gorsich)
- It does not matter what the meaning is of Microsoft jargon like `breaking`, if they talk about debatable things like "unneeded"; I'd propose new jargon like `unneeded build warnings`
- Both event handlers are similar in that they can receive the same number and type of arguments, it is just strange behaviour by VisualStudio (or DevExpress CodeRush??)
- Unused parameters do not incur maintenance and performance costs, instead, removing those may incur costs later when they may be needed and the developer has to "know" that they can be added back in
- I am now looking how to configure VS to suppress all warnings about unused parameters

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure. But i think that if you remove the parameters the function may not get called anymore. Since the expected signature changed.

Comment: I was thinking exactly like you, but the MS help text suggests otherwise, still confusing.

Comment: Maybe they're smart enough to also call the parameterless function? it would be funny to test what it happens if you add both a Page_Load() and a Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) for the same page

Comment: Just tried removing the parameters on the asp.net app I'm developing.  It made no difference (obviously I wasn't using the parameters).  No compiler warning either way.
//   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
   protected void Page_Load(){

Comment: @Jacopo It would be fun to remove the unused parameters, but this is our important company web site, and I do not want to risk getting into obscure bugs sometime just because I wanted to get rid of silly build warnings.

Comment: sure, sure, i meant to do these tries in a test environment. If it is for work, i'll sugguest to leave them as they are untill you are told to remove them. It's better to have warnings than hidden/hard-to-discover bugs