# Binding event on the passed value in a setter

Tags: c#, wpf, events

When assigning the Task property with a value, and binding the value with a delegate eventhandler. Does the value get selected for the GarbageCollection once a new value passes by? As per my understanding because the system does no longer have a reference to the old value, it gets flagged for garbage collection.

```
  private ITask _task;

  public ITask Task
        {
            get => _task;
            private set
            {
                if(_task != value)
                {
                    if(value != null)
                        value.PropertyChanged += (s, e) =>
                            {
                                if(((ITask)s).Status == TaskStatus.Ready)
                                    RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(ButtonCommand));
                            };

                    _task = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You are not unsubscribing `value` from the event handler, and as such it will never be collected, meaning your event handler will be called multiple times. You need to unsubscribe `_task` before with `-=`, this means you'll also either need a reference to your anonymous function like [so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183367/unsubscribe-anonymous-method-in-c-sharp) or make a method out of your handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298261/do-event-handlers-stop-garbage-collection-from-occurring), the anonymous event handler will not prevent garbage collection. However, any object that read `Task` before the new value is assigned and still holds the result will keep a reference to the old value of `Task`, preventing garbage collection.