# How can I create an easy-to-access 'self-unsubscribe' delegate in C#?

Tags: c#, delegates

First of all, sorry for bad title as I don't know many correct terms in C#. I found working 'self-unsubscribing' delegate from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183367/unsubscribe-anonymous-method-in-c-sharp). This code below works (at least for me).

```
private delegate void V;
private V delVoid;

private void SelfUnsubscribeDelVoid()
{
    void Unsubscriber()
    {
        // Some operation
        delVoid -= Unsubscriber;
    }

    DelVoid += Unsubscriber;
}
```

However, as I use many 'self-unsubscribing' delegates, there will be a lot variation of `SelfUnsubscribeDelVoid()`, each handle different delegates. Therefore, I make one static function with delegate as input parameter. This way, I don't have to make many similar functions. Here's what I come up with.

```
public static class Delegates
{
    public delegate void V();

    public static void SelfUnsubscribeDelVoid(V theDelegate, V functionToExecute)
    {
        void Unsubscriber()
        {
            functionToExecute();
            theDelegate -= Unsubscriber;
        }

        theDelegate += Unsubscriber;
    }

}

public class Caller
{
    private Delegates.V OnDoingSomething;
    
    public void FunctionA()
    {
        Delegates.SelfUnsubscribeDelVoid(OnDoingSomething, FunctionB);
        OnDoingSomething();     // FunctionB is not invoked
    }

    private void FunctionB()
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, my code doesn't work. A bit of try and error raise a likelihood that the `onDoingSomething` delegate is not 'linked' with the input `theDelegate`, as if they are two different delegates.
Are there mistakes in my code? Is my approach incorrect? Or is what I want simply impossible to do?
**Thanks in advance** :)

**Edit** sample code should've followed common naming convention.

Comment: What are you trying to do, actually? Why must those delegates self-unsubscribe?

Comment: `TheDelegate += Unsubscriber` is equivalent to `TheDelegate = (V)Delegate.Combine(TheDelegate, Unsubscriber)`.  Your question is essentially "why does assigning my local variable `TheDelegate` have no impact on `OnDoingSomething`?". Because `TheDelegate` is a copy of the current value of `OnDoingSomething`, not a reference to it.

Comment: @Fildor I want to make the `FunctionB` to be delegated and the forget about it. Reducing the burden of "where should I put the unsubscriber".

Comment: @JeremyLakeman So, technically, what I want to accomplish is simply impossible to achieve?

Comment: Well you could use a `ref` parameter in this specific case. (I'd strongly encourage you to follow .NET naming conventions in sample code, btw - it would make the sample much easier to understand.)

Comment: @JonSkeet My bad, I'll fix the naming rule soon. I've tried using `ref` for `TheDelegate`, unfortunately, compiler get error as it is called in local function (`ref` parameter cannot be used in local function).

Comment: Ah yes, I hadn't thought about that aspect. Of course, you could potentially create your own "mutable delegate" class which wraps the actual delegate... it really depends on how you later use this.